# Primeiro parâmetro não é retornado ao fazer parse da URL completa usando URLSearchParams

Tags: javascript, url

Estou tentando usar o `URLSearchParams`, mas ele não funciona se eu tento obter o primeiro parâmetro da URL; por exemplo `get('id')`, que retorna `null`. Porém funciona com qualquer outro parâmetro.

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.game.gamelab&ref=ex.com&urlk=45');

console.log(urlParams.get('id'));   // null    ?????
console.log(urlParams.get('ref'));  // ex.com
console.log(urlParams.get('urlk')); // 45
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está utilizando o construtor `URLSearchParams` para fazer o *parse* de um URL inteiro. Isso é errado.

Para fazer o *parse* da URL, deve-se utilizar o construtor `URL`. Os parâmetros de URL então poderão ser acessados pela propriedade `searchParams`.

Exemplo:

```js
const url = new URL('https://pt.stackoverflow.com?foo=1&bar=baz');

console.log(url.searchParams.get('foo')); // 1
console.log(url.searchParams.get('bar')); // baz
```

Para utilizar o construtor `URLSearchParams` você deve se certificar que só está passando dados codificados no formato [*URL encoded*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). No formato de URLs, o que está depois *da* interrogação está nesse formato. Portanto, se você passa *toda* a URL, há uma violação desse contrato.

No exemplo da pergunta nenhum erro é levantado porque toda a URL até o `=` é interpretada como o nome do primeiro parâmetro. Veja como foi analisado:

```js
console.log([...new URLSearchParams('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.game.gamelab&ref=ex.com&urlk=45')]);
```